# Accessing a Samba server from a new Windows system

Tags: samba, rhel5

I have had a samba server running on a linux (RHEL5) box for a while and I have mounted a shared directory on a Windows PC. I just got a new Windows 7 laptop and trying to access the same server, but I am not able to connect it. I get this error:

> Check the spelling of the name. Otherwise, there might be a problem
>   with your network. To try to identify and resolve network problems,
>   click Diagnose.

Or, I get this:

> \\hostname is not accessible. You might not have permission to use
>   this network resource. Contact the administrator of this server to
>   find out if you have access permissions.

I can still access the location from different other Windows hosts in the network with my credentials. It's just that I am not able to access this resource from my new PC.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe your new system has not been added into the domain?  or you have configured the workgroup incorrectly depending on which is being used at your site (probably the domain).  If the former, your systems administrator will have to take care of this.  If the latter, it is a simple change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been my experience that WIn7 isn't willing (out of the box as it where) to connect with samba shares. It you are using samba as a domain controller, you are forced to change certain registry keys.

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINESYSTEMCurrentControlSetservicesLanmanWorkstationParameters:
>
> "DomainCompatibilityMode" = 1
>
> "DNSNameResolutionRequired" = 0
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINESYSTEMCurrentControlSetservicesNetlogonParameters:
>
> "RequireSignOnSeal" = 0
>
> "RequireStrongKey" = 0

And if you are just using a workgroup (assuming the the Win7 box is in the workgroup) you still need to "degrade" Win7. All this of course is depending on the version of samba you are using. You can degrade Win7 by going to

> Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Local Security Policy

Select:

> Local Policies -> Security Options

and changing these two options

> "Network security: LAN Manager authentication level" -> Send LM & NTLM
> responses
>
> "Minimum session security for NTLM SSP" -> uncheck: Require
> 128-bit encryption

Quick & dirty but I hope it was helpful.

Comment: Thanks. These helped me:
Microsoft network client: Digitally sign communications (if server agrees)  : Disabled 
Network security: LAN Manager authentication level  : Send LM & NTLM - use NTLMv2 session security if negotiated. 
Domain member: Digitally encrypt or sign secure channel data (always)  : Disabled 
Domain member: Require strong (Windows 2000 or later) session key  : Disabled

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Try to access the share by using IP address instead of the hostname:

```
\\192.168.55.55
```

Depending on what does your DNS and DHCP, your windows machine could be missing the DNS records for your RHEL5 box.